# Can I use Reflection with ProGuard obfuscated classes?

Tags: java, android, reflection, proguard

I have a certain class method which I want to `invoke` using `Reflection`.
Here is an example of my code in my `Activity onCreate`:

```
try {
    aMethod = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("myMethodName", SomeParameter.class);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run it directly from Android Studio, it works, but when I create a release version, the method name is not automatically changed by ProGuard. What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ProGuard documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/home#reflection) mentions the following:

> It is generally impossible to compute which classes have to be
> preserved (with their original names), since the class names might be
> read from a configuration file, for instance. You therefore have to
> specify them in your ProGuard configuration, with the same simple
> -keep options.

However, there are **SOME** cases in which ProGuard automatically handles Reflection. Those are the following: *(please refer to the documentation for the most recent list)*

- `Class.forName("SomeClass") SomeClass.class`
- `SomeClass.class.getField("someField")`
- `SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField("someField")`
- `SomeClass.class.getMethod("someMethod", new Class[] {})`
- `SomeClass.class.getMethod("someMethod", new Class[] { A.class })`
- `SomeClass.class.getMethod("someMethod", new Class[] { A.class, B.class })`
- `SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", new Class[] {})`
- `SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", new Class[] { A.class })`
- `SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", new Class[] { A.class, B.class })`
- `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(SomeClass.class, "someField")`
- `AtomicLongFieldUpdater.newUpdater(SomeClass.class, "someField")`
- `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(SomeClass.class, SomeType.class, "someField")`

So, in my case, my error was that I was getting the class using `getClass()`.
The following line did work great.

```
aMethod = MainActivity.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethodName", SomeParameter.class);
```